# Standalone PowerPoint/Impress replacement?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I often use AbiWord for word processing, since it has a better UI than OpenOffice. Considering that there's also a standalone spreadsheet - gnumeric, is there a standalone presentation editor/viewer in the vein of PowerPoint or Impress?

Only installing Impress seems wasteful since I have to install much of the OpenOffice backend as well. PowerPoint Viewer is fine unless I find I need to edit a slide - I'm aware of these alternatives.

Portable, or low-dependency software would be preferred. The question is primarily for Windows systems (though I'd upvote any good Linux-based answers), and compatability with at least classic Office PowerPoint slides would be essential.

Comment: FYI--ancient question attracted nothing but a spam answer; now in the [close review queue](http://superuser.com/review/close/608962?filter-closereason=offtopic).

Comment: Don't know if this has been overtaken by events, but it's a good question and worth reposting on Software Recs.

Comment: I've not needed to use do a presentation since, and I moved off abiword. And of course gdocs and the like. But yeah, this question would be better, updated on SR.